# Store disabled date in database for datepicker in orboen form

Tags: orbeon

I wanted to store disabled date in the database and use data to dim the days of the datepicker in orbeon form.

I did the following steps:

1. Create database services with sql "select dt from disabled_dt"
2. Create action with Condition "Run on creation only" and run action when "the from loads after the controls are ready".  Using the above database service and set Service Respose Actions as "Save to Dataset disabled-data-set"
3. Create a datepicker, and, in "Dates to Exclude", add "for $d in fr:dataset('disabled-data-set')/row/dt return xs:date($d)" as formula.

But I found day at the datepicker not dimmed.  I think the formula in "Dates to Exclude" is not correct.  Does anyone know how to set it correctly?

Comment: First, let's check what is returned by your database service. Could you add a Calculated Value field to your form, set the calculation to `saxon:serialize(fr:dataset('disabled-data-set'), 'xml')`. When you run the form, what XML are you getting in the form?

Comment: The value returned lots of xmlns definition but no data.  However, when changed the action condition to "Run always" and run action when the control appears or changes its value, it returned "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><row><dt>2020-07-01</dt></row><row><dt>2020-07-15</dt></row><row><dt>2020-07-31</dt></row></response>".  When I set "Dates to Exclude" to "for $d in fr:dataset('disabled-data-set')/row return xs:date($d/dt), the date disable function becomes work in the datepicker.  My problem is solved.  Thank you for your suggestion.  It is helpful for debugging.

Comment: Excellent, I am glad you found what the problem was, and thank you for the update. ‑Alex